# How do these mass advantage/disadvantage rolls work out statistically?

Tags: dnd-5e, dice, statistics

On an [unrelated question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94046/what-exactly-does-great-weapon-fighting-allow-you-to-reroll#comment217350_94048), user [Yakk](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8217/yakk) shared the [following bit of advice in a comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94046/what-exactly-does-great-weapon-fighting-allow-you-to-reroll#comment217350_94048) to keep combat moving quickly for mass numbers where advantage/disadvantage might apply:

> Mass attacks with disadvantage: work out target number. Roll # of goblin
>   d20. Count how many hit. Now roll those again, and they only hit if
>   they hit the second time. Nothing crits (the odds of it happening
>   where 1 in 400 to start, so we'll say screw it). For advantage, reroll
>   misses, treat both 19s and 20s as 20s on the first roll, and 20s as
>   19s on the reroll. (The difference between this and doing it manually
>   is tiny).

How does this affect the odds of:

- Hitting with advantage/disadvantage?
- Missing with advantage/disadvantage?
- Critical hits with advantage/disadvantage?
- Critical misses (natural 1's) with advantage/disadvantage?

Bonus question, what is the total hit/miss/crit rate for the entire group of goblins?

(I am aware there are other ways of handling mass combat and I know the general probabilities for advantage/disadvantage (those are easy to figure out on my own).  On this question I am specifically concerned with the probabilities as described in the quoted text.)

Answer (score 8):

Hitting and missing is unchanged. A miss with the lower of two die with disadvantage is a hit, and a hit with the higher of two die is a hit, and this system replicates that without performing any redundant rolls.

What this system does modify is critical hits, although only slightly. The chance of a critical hit with disadvantage goes from 1/400 to 0 (or 0/400). The chance of a critical hit with advantage goes from 39/400 to 2/20 (or 40/400).

A critical miss is still just a miss, and this system doesn't seem to account for them, so they'd remain unchanged.

Comment: I guess it's a little simpler than I thought.  I'll admit I hadn't thought much about how it might work out before I posted the question but now I see it actually works out quite well without much change to the odds at all.

Comment: If the fight is massive enough, you *might* plausibly want to care about the 1/400 chance of a crit with disadvantage. (With 20 attackers, the probability of one of them critting is roughly 1/20.) In any case, if you do care, it's easy enough to handle: before rerolling the successes, set any nat 20s aside and reroll them separately. If any of them rolls a nat 20 again, that's a crit.

Answer (score 4):

**Warning - maths ahead**

### Single hit probability

Start with defining 3 events:

\$M\$: A miss with a single attack

\$H\$: A hit with a single attack

\$C\$: A critical hit with a single attack

It is obvious that \$M\$ and \$H\$ are complimentary events. That is, if you miss you don't hit and vice versa, so: \$P(M) = 1 - P(H)\$.

It is also obvious that \$C\$ is a sub-event of \$H\$. That is, you can't get a critical hit unless you hit, so: \$P(H\cap C) = P(C)\$.

5e does not have any such thing as a critical miss so I am not going to deal with this.

We also define the target number \$t\$, as the number needed to roll or above to get a hit. \$t\$ must be between 2 and 20 inclusive, since a 1 always misses and a 20 always hits.

**Normal attacks**

$$\begin{align}
P(H) = h & = {21 - t \over 20} \\
P(M) = m & = {t - 1 \over 20} \\
P(C) & = {1 \over 20} \\
P(C|H) = c & = {P(C\cap H) \over P(H)} \\
& = {P(C) \over P(H)} \\
& = {1 \over 21-t} \\
\end{align}$$

**Advantaged attacks**

$$\begin{align}
P(H) = h & = 1 - \left({t - 1 \over 20}\right)^2 \\
& = {400 - (t-1)^2 \over 400} \\
P(M) = m & = \left({t - 1 \over 20}\right)^2 \\
P(C) &= 1 - \left({19 \over 20}\right)^2 \\
& = {39 \over 400} \\
P(C|H) = c & = {39 \over {400 - (t-1)^2}}{} \\
\end{align}$$

**Disadvantaged attacks**

$$\begin{align}
P(H) = h & = {(21 - t)^2 \over 400} \\
P(M) = m & = {400 - (21 - t)^2 \over 400} \\
P(C) &= \left({1 \over 20}\right)^2 \\
& = {1 \over 400} \\
P(C|H) = c & = {1 \over (21 - t)^2} \\
\end{align}$$

Now, you can pick your target number and get numerical solutions to these but I will continue to treat them algebraically. The important point to note is that the chance of critical hit given a hit was achieved is dependent on the target number so the quote that dismisses it as inconsequential in **not** valid. For example, if \$t\$ = 20 then **every hit is a critical hit** irrespective of advantage/disadvantage.

### Multiple attack probability

This is a straightforward application of the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Specifically, for \$n\$ attacks, the probability of \$k\$ hits is:

$$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k}h^km^{1-k}$$

And the probability that of these \$k\$, \$j\$ will be critical hits is:

$$P(Y=j|X=k)= \binom{n}{k}h^km^{1-k}\binom{k}{j}c^j(1-c)^{1-j}$$

The mean number of hits is simply \$nh\$ and the mean number of critical hits is \$nhc\$.

### Proposed alternative

**Normal attacks**

There is no difference.

**Advantaged attacks**

This gives a straight chance of a critical hit of \${1 \over {10}} {({40\over 400})}\$ where the actual chance is \$39 \over 400\$.

I won't take this any further because you can actually do this strictly in accordance with the rules with no additional work:

- Roll all the dice,
- reroll all the misses,
- look at *all* the dice now on the table (originals and rerrolls), 20s are critical hits and all the other hits are just hits.

**Disadvantaged attacks**

This obviously reduces the chance of a critical hit, from \$ 1 \over 400\$ to 0.

You can actually make this in accordance with RAW with one tiny additional step:

- Roll all the dice,
- all the misses are misses,
- reroll all the 20s *away from the other hits*, if these miss they miss, if they hit they hit and if you get a 20 they are criticals,
- reroll all the other hits, if they hit they hit and if they miss they miss - these cannot be criticals.

Comment: Your proposal for advantaged attacks does not take into account that a reroll on a hit could result in a crit.

Comment: You could take this calculated probability for the chance to hit and add it to the general damage question http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93212/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-hundreds-of-attacks/93217#93217, or consult the table in http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14690/how-does-rolling-two-dice-and-taking-the-highest-affect-the-average-outcome/14691#14691 for the "C," chance to hit.  However, my discreet math is at its limit....it would be a separate question I guess, but how to make the equations simulate x rounds of combat...taking into account creatures dying each round?

Comment: Also, not sure what the h and m is in your equations....and not sure what use the "probability of k hits" is in practice.  You just want the avg number of hits.  Do those equations simplify more when actually used?

Comment: @Ἄρτεμις h, m & c are defined for each of normal, advantage and disadvantage in the first part. The probability of k hits is the probability of k hits - for example, if n=5 you can use this to work out the probability of k=0,1,2,3,4 or 5 hits.

Comment: The lowercase through me off.  Well, I guess that is what the OP was asking, but not sure if that is what he meant to ask, lol.